# convert data in columns to json

Tags: json

I've data in text file in format:

```
alex street1 253465873 alex123@google.com
john street2 442893646 3jj33@google.com
kevin street3 125234763 ke1vn@yahoo.com
```

I need to convert this data to json format with headers:
`"name" "street" "phone" "e-mail"`

Comment: ... JSON doesn't really have "headers", does it? did you mean *field names*?

Comment: you rigth, this is what I'm actually mean

Comment: @username Please remember to [accept the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for your question, when [someone answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and you see this answer is what you need, it's a way to say "thank you" and to help any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 4):

You can read *raw input* and split it into space-delimited fields using `jq` as follows:

```
$ cat file.txt | 
    jq -nR '[inputs | split(" ") | { "name": .[0], "street": .[1], "phone": .[2], "e-mail": .[3] }]'
[
  {
    "name": "alex",
    "street": "street1",
    "phone": "253465873",
    "e-mail": "alex123@google.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "john",
    "street": "street2",
    "phone": "442893646",
    "e-mail": "3jj33@google.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "kevin",
    "street": "street3",
    "phone": "125234763",
    "e-mail": "ke1vn@yahoo.com"
  }
]
```

Alternatively, for simple (non-nested) tabular data, you could use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
mlr --inidx --ojson --jvstack rename '1,name,2,street,3,phone,4,e-mail' file.txt
```

Comment: Mainly out of curiosity: why `-n` and `inputs`? Your `jq` command seems to work without them too.

Comment: @fra-san hmm good observation, tbh I don't know whether they're strictly equivalent or if there are other things going on under the hood with `[inputs]`

Comment: @steeldriver Sorry -- as roaima noted, the two commands (with or without `-n` and `inputs`) are not equivalent - the first one creates an array of _n_ elements, the second one creates _n_ single-element arrays. I somehow missed it, I'm deleting my comments here.

Comment: @fra-san well your version may be closer to what the OP wants - let's see if they clarify expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
$ column --table --separator=" " --table-columns name,street,phone,email --json test.txt

{
   "table": [
      {
         "name": "alex",
         "street": "street1",
         "phone": "253465873",
         "email": "alex123@google.com"
      },{
         "name": "john",
         "street": "street2",
         "phone": "442893646",
         "email": "3jj33@google.com"
      },{
         "name": "kevin",
         "street": "street3",
         "phone": "125234763",
         "email": "ke1vn@yahoo.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You have to say what implementation of `column` you're using. I'm just getting `column: illegal option -- -` followed by `usage: column [-tx] [-c columns] [-s sep] [file ...]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to convert the header-less and space-delimited data into JSON:

```bash
$ mlr --n2j label name,street,phone,e-mail file
{ "name": "alex", "street": "street1", "phone": 253465873, "e-mail": "alex123@google.com" }
{ "name": "john", "street": "street2", "phone": 442893646, "e-mail": "3jj33@google.com" }
{ "name": "kevin", "street": "street3", "phone": 125234763, "e-mail": "ke1vn@yahoo.com" }
```

The output is a separate JSON object per input record.  The `--n2j` option is a shorthand for `--inidx` ("input is implicitly-integer-indexed (nidx)") in combination with `--ojson` ("output is JSON").

The `label` sub-command renames the fields in order.

Would you want to wrap the set of generated objects in an array, use `--jlistwrap`:

```bash
$ mlr --n2j --jlistwrap label name,street,phone,e-mail file
[
{ "name": "alex", "street": "street1", "phone": 253465873, "e-mail": "alex123@google.com" }
,{ "name": "john", "street": "street2", "phone": 442893646, "e-mail": "3jj33@google.com" }
,{ "name": "kevin", "street": "street3", "phone": 125234763, "e-mail": "ke1vn@yahoo.com" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this awk command:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i="\""$i"\"";printf $i" "}};{printf"\n"}' infile

"alex" "street1" "253465873" "alex123@google.com" 
"john" "street2" "442893646" "3jj33@google.com" 
"kevin" "street3" "125234763" "ke1vn@yahoo.com"
```